# How to fetch hours from m8[ns] object in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe like shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time':['2166-01-09 14:00:00','2166-01-09 14:08:00','2166-01-09 16:00:00','2166-01-09 20:00:00',
                       '2166-01-09 04:00:00','2166-01-10 05:00:00','2166-01-10 06:00:00','2166-01-10 07:00:00','2166-01-10 11:00:00',
                       '2166-01-10 11:30:00','2166-01-10 12:00:00','2166-01-10 13:00:00','2166-01-10 13:30:00']})
```

I am trying to find a time difference between rows. For which I did the below

```
df['time2'] = df['time'].shift(-1)
df['tdiff'] = (df['time2'] - df['time'])
```

So, my result looks like as shown below

[image]

I found out that there exists a function like `dt.days` and I tried

```
df['tdiff'].dt.days
```

but it only gives the day component but am looking for something like 'hours` component

However, I would like to have my output like as shown below

[image]

I am sorry that I am not sure how to calculate the hour equivalent of negative time in row no 3. Might be that's an data issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pandas is possible convert timedeltas to seconds by [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) and then divide by `3600`:

```
df['tdiff'] = (df['time2'] - df['time']).dt.total_seconds() / 3600
print (df)
                  time               time2      tdiff
0  2166-01-09 14:00:00 2166-01-09 14:08:00   0.133333
1  2166-01-09 14:08:00 2166-01-09 16:00:00   1.866667
2  2166-01-09 16:00:00 2166-01-09 20:00:00   4.000000
3  2166-01-09 20:00:00 2166-01-09 04:00:00 -16.000000
4  2166-01-09 04:00:00 2166-01-10 05:00:00  25.000000
5  2166-01-10 05:00:00 2166-01-10 06:00:00   1.000000
6  2166-01-10 06:00:00 2166-01-10 07:00:00   1.000000
7  2166-01-10 07:00:00 2166-01-10 11:00:00   4.000000
8  2166-01-10 11:00:00 2166-01-10 11:30:00   0.500000
9  2166-01-10 11:30:00 2166-01-10 12:00:00   0.500000
10 2166-01-10 12:00:00 2166-01-10 13:00:00   1.000000
11 2166-01-10 13:00:00 2166-01-10 13:30:00   0.500000
12 2166-01-10 13:30:00                 NaT        NaN
```

Comment: Will try. Upvoted. Can you share the link of this `dt` appraoch

Comment: you can add || for the positive values for tdiff as the time difference is never negative as in the 3rd row.

Comment: @shyamzzp - would you mind giving an example on where to add this `||` operator? I am new to Python and not sure where to have this

Comment: @SSMK the simple method would be adding an if statement [if value for the tdiff is negative then multiply the same with -1] else as it is.

Comment: @SSMK - Or simpliest is `df['tdiff'] = (df['time2'] - df['time']).dt.total_seconds().abs() / 3600`

Comment: @shyamzzp - hmmm, why do you think so? It is pandas function [`Series.abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.abs.html)